# Why cannot I use value in constant as custom type definition?

Tags: typescript, types, constants, typescript-typings, custom-type

This is not compilable

```
export const QuantityModes = {
    POSITIVE: 'POSITIVE', 
    NEGATIVE: 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY: 'ANY', 
};

export type QuantityMode = QuantityModes.POSITIVE | QuantityModes.NEGATIVE | QuantityModes.ANY;
```

This is compilable

```
export const QuantityModes = {
    POSITIVE: 'POSITIVE',
    NEGATIVE: 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY: 'ANY',
};

export type QuantityMode = 'POSITIVE' | 'NEGATIVE' | 'ANY';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem you have is that the type of the properties are actually all `string` not string literal types like you might expect. To fix this we can either use a type assertion:

```
export const QuantityModes = {
    POSITIVE: 'POSITIVE' as 'POSITIVE', 
    NEGATIVE: 'NEGATIVE' as 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY: 'ANY' as 'ANY', 
};
```

Use a helper function to hint to the compiler we want type literals:

```
export const QuantityModes = (<T extends { [P in keyof T]: P }>(o: T)=> o)({
    POSITIVE: 'POSITIVE', 
    NEGATIVE: 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY: 'ANY', 
})
```

Or, starting in 3.4 (unrelease yet), you can write `as const`:

```
export const QuantityModes = {
    POSITIVE: 'POSITIVE', 
    NEGATIVE: 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY: 'ANY', 
} as const
```

You can type a type relative to another type but the syntax is different. Firstly if you want to access the type of a property the syntax is `type['propName']` (also called an [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)). But you want to access the type of a constant, to do that you need to use `typeof const`.  So you could write:

```
export type QuantityMode = typeof QuantityModes["POSITIVE"] | typeof QuantityModes["NEGATIVE"] | typeof QuantityModes["ANY"];
```

You can also use union to simplify a bit with the same result:

```
export type QuantityMode = typeof QuantityModes["POSITIVE" | "NEGATIVE" | "ANY"];
```

If the union contains all property names, then we can just use `keyof type` to get a union of all property names within a type (ensuring all future additions are also automatically added to the type)

```
export type QuantityMode = typeof QuantityModes[keyof typeof QuantityModes];
```

Since in this case the property name and the property type are the same we could even just use `keyof`:

```
export type QuantityMode = keyof typeof QuantityModes;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering it in details. Every JS developer should learn advanced TS to a certain extent

Comment: @tom10271 could not agree more :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a string enum instead? It's both a type (for TypeScript compiler) and a value (JavaScript pseudo-map object, equivalent to your `const QuantityModes`). There's still some limitations but it's more handy.

```
enum QuantityMode {
    POSITIVE = 'POSITIVE', 
    NEGATIVE = 'NEGATIVE',
    ANY = 'ANY', 
}

const a_ko: QuantityMode = 'POSITIVE';     // Error: Type '"POSITIVE"' is not assignable to type 'QuantityMode'
const a_ok_1 = QuantityMode.POSITIVE;      // Strict use
const a_ok_2 = 'POSITIVE' as QuantityMode; // Lax use

// Composable within an union type
type QuantityStrictMode = QuantityMode.POSITIVE | QuantityMode.NEGATIVE;

const b_ko  : QuantityStrictMode = 'POSITIVE';            // Error: Type '"POSITIVE"' is not assignable to type 'QuantityStrictMode'
const b_ok_1: QuantityStrictMode = QuantityMode.POSITIVE; // Strict use
const b_ok_2 = 'POSITIVE' as QuantityStrictMode;          // Lax use
```